# Cordova build results in error on iOS after installing org.apache.cordova.network-information

Tags: ios, cordova

Hi I just started with a fresh structure for a cordova project and I needed to install this plugin org.apache.cordova.network-information.

I am using cordova 3.5.0.

After installing it and running cordova build I got this error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability connectionRequired] in CDVReachability.o
      -[CDVReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability stopNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/EconnectHybrid.app/EconnectHybrid normal i386
(1 failure)
Command finished with error code 65: /Users/dev/Development/ncoi-econnect-hybrid/platforms/ios/cordova/build 
Error: /Users/dev/Development/ncoi-econnect-hybrid/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 65
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:755:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:822:5)
isdc30408:ncoi-econnect-hybrid dev$
```

If I try to build from XCODE I get this error:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityGetFlags", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability connectionRequired] in CDVReachability.o
      -[CDVReachability currentReachabilityStatus] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithAddress", referenced from:
      +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithAddress:] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityCreateWithName", referenced from:
      +[CDVReachability reachabilityWithHostName:] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilityUnscheduleFromRunLoop", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability stopNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
  "_SCNetworkReachabilitySetCallback", referenced from:
      -[CDVReachability startNotifier] in CDVReachability.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sounds like the `SystemConfiguration.framework` was supposed to have been added automatically by the org.apache.cordova.network-information plugin but wasn't.

I ended up manually adding the `SystemConfiguration.framework` in `Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries` per the comments in the following and it fixed it for me:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-6443

Comment: Ha, this has been driving me crazy for while. +1!